# Why Room select query is not working via c++?

Tags: android, c++, select, android-room

I create the database via Room and gave the path to C++ developers via JNI. All data are inserting from C++ side by using `sqlpp`, then i am executing SQL query and not getting fresh datas. If i kill app then start again, SQL query is returning all datas.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
LocalDatabase provideLocalDatabase(@DatabaseInfo String dbName, Context context) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context, LocalDatabase.class, dbName)
          .setJournalMode(RoomDatabase.JournalMode.WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING)
          .build();
}
```

MessageDao

```
@Dao
public abstract class MessageDao implements BaseDao<Message> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages")
    public abstract Flowable<Message> getMessage();
}
```

Sending db path to C++

```
String uiDbPath = MyApp.applicationContext.getDatabasePath(AppConstants.DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
send_db_path_to_c_plus_plus(uiDbPath);
```

We are using JournalMode.WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING mode, after inserting data to database i am checking the database to make sure all data are exits. As a result i am seeing all data, but select query is not returning. How can i solve the issue please help? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1** C++ parts

```
int64_t insert(manager::db::connection & conn, int64_t conv_id, int64_t author_id, const std::string & data)
{
   auto conn_guard = manager::db::make_connection_guard(conn);
   {
       LOG_TRACE("db::insert(in_msg) - BEGIN conv_id={0} author_id={1}", conv_id, author_id);

   const auto tab_in_msg = manager::db::tables::InMsgs{};

   auto tx = start_transaction(conn_guard.native());
   conn_guard.native()(insert_into(tab_in_msg).set(tab_in_msg.conversationId = conv_id, tab_in_msg.authorId = author_id, tab_in_msg.data = data));
   int64_t rowid = conn_guard.native().last_insert_id();
   tx.commit();

   LOG_TRACE("db::insert(in_msg) - END rowid={0}", rowid);
   return rowid;
   }
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant C++ code too.

Comment: @Shawn i have added c++ parts

Comment: @yigit please se the above problem?